# Intersect two polygons but preserving the shape of one

Tags: point, buffer, ellipse

I have two polygons layers; a selection of land titles and a buffer layer. I want to intersect the two layers but preserve the shape of the land title polygon to show all the land plots that touch the buffer layer.

The buffer is the green hatched area and the land titles is the layer below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a classic example of "Select by Location"!

To use it:
**Vector > Research Tools > Select by Location**, where:

```
- *Select features from* = Land Titles layer

- *Where the features* = Intersect

- *By comparing* = Buffer layer
```

The output will be a new layer containing only those Land Title polygons that intersect the Buffer layer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `select by expression` on your layer `land_titles` with this expression (replace `'buffer'` with the name of your buffer layer):

```
intersects ($geometry,geometry (get_feature_by_id ('buffer', 1)))
```

*Screenshot: Layer with `land_titles` (orange) and `buffer`-layer (blue). Applied on the `land_titles`-layer, `select by expression` with the expression from above selects all polygons that intersect with the buffer (highlighted in yellow): use the selection for further processing, to create an attribute (`intersects_buffer`) of copy the selection to a new layer:*
[image]